# Line numbers break scroll margin

Tags: scrolling, line-numbers

I'm trying to set a scroll margin to emacs with the `scroll-margin` variable, but I've noticed that when you do that and you have `display-line-numbers-mode` enabled, the scrolling doesn't work properly when coming up from the bottom of the file.

[Here's a gif illustrating the issue](https://media.giphy.com/media/2uIbVp7Z7l2OiQHkVh/giphy.gif)

Notice that, when scrolling down, it scrolls properly, but, when the cursor reaches the bottom of the file, and starts going up, it doesn't respect the scroll-margin until the bottom of the file is not visible anymore.

If I disable `display-line-numbers-mode` the scrolling works properly. Is there a way to achieve scroll margin along with line numbers without falling back to `linum-mode`?

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the screen gif that illustrates the issue.  Could you please add a little more description to the question to tell us what to look for.  Eli Z. is the person who wrote the native line-numbers and I have not seen him ever post a comment or answer on emacs.stackexchange.com.  He does read and respond to posts on https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ and also any bug report that gets filed:  `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I personally do not touch the `scroll-margin` variable.  I like to use `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` -- contrary to the posts regarding `scroll-conservatively` that set the value to a hundred million trillion, anything larger than 100 will suffice.

Comment: @lawlist I do have `scroll-conservatively` enabled along with `scroll-margin`. Notice that, when scrolling down, it does scroll "conservatively", but, when the cursor reaches the bottom of the file, and starts going up, it doesn't respect the `scroll-margin` until the bottom of the file is not visible anymore.

Comment: I edited my question with the information above. I'll try to post it on reddit too and maybe file a bug if that's the case. Thanks!

Comment: When the `scroll-margin` is at its default setting of `0` and when I have `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` and native line numbers active, I am unable to reproduce the behavior depicted in the gif that illustrates the issue.  I would suggest adjusting `scroll-conservatively` within the guidelines of the doc-string and leave `scroll-margin` at its default setting of `0`.  To the extent you wish to combine the two variables to non-default specifications and you believe there is a bug, then a bug-report would be appropriate.  These are things in the C code base that cannot be fixed with Lisp.

Comment: @lawlist I was able fix this with some lisp and posted in my answer. Thanks for the help. But I think it's really a bug after all, and I also found this report on the spacemacs repo https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround using an advice around the `previous-line` funtion. Here's the code:

```
(defvar sm-use-visual-line t)

(defun sm-fix-enable()
  (advice-add 'previous-line :around 'sm-fix))

(defun sm-fix-disable()
  (advice-remove 'previous-line 'sm-fix))

(defun sm-get-lines-from-top ()
  (if sm-use-visual-line
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (count-screen-lines (point) (window-start)))
    (- (line-number-at-pos (point)) (line-number-at-pos (window-start)) )))

(defun sm-fix(old-function &rest args)
  (apply old-function args)
  (let ((diff (- scroll-margin (sm-get-lines-from-top))))
    (when (> diff 0)
    (scroll-down diff))))
```